# How to bind formControl value to a form input

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have angular  component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';

import {FormBuilder, FormGroup,Validators,FormArray,FormControl,} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-collaborator-detail',
    template: `
    <h1> This is form</h1>
    <form [formGroup]="collaboratorForm">
    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email address" formControlName="emailAddress">
    </div>
</form>`,
})
export class CollaboratorDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(@Inject(FormBuilder) private fb: FormBuilder) {}

    collaboratorForm: FormGroup;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.initCollaboratorForm();
    }

    initCollaboratorForm() {
        this.collaboratorForm = this.fb.group({
            emailAddress: [
                { value: 'some.email@gmail.com', disable: true },
                [Validators.email, Validators.required],
            ]
        });
    }
}
```

I expect, that value: "some-email@gmail.com" will be visible as a input value. But instead of it, visible value is: "[object Object]".

What I am doing wrong here?

Plunker urL: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/wu1ow98ai00gqJ4s

Comment: Try `{ value: 'some.email@gmail.com', disabled: true },` you have `disable` instead of `disabled`

Answer (score 1):

There's no property called `disable` in the [AbstractControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#disabled) API (which is the base class for all the form controls), it should be `disabled`.

```
{ value: 'some.email@gmail.com', disabled: true }
```